# Chrome Horizontal Scroll Body Right

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The right extent of the document body in chrome is moving away from the edge of the window during horizontal scrolling...

### Chrome

[image]

### Firefox`enter code here`

[image]

```js
    $(function() {
      self.resizeTo(200, window.innerHeight);
      $(window).resize( function () {
        console.log(document.body.clientWidth);
        $(document.body).scrollLeft($(document.body).innerWidth()/2);
      })
    })
```

```css
    body {
      border: 1px solid #cca0a0;
      position: relative;
      min-width:100px;
    }
    #viz {
      position: relative;
      height: 500px;
      width: 1000px;
      outline: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    #tagRight {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 50%;
      outline: 1px solid #cca0a0;
    }
    #tagBottom {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      outline: 1px solid #cca0a0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="viz"></div>
  <div id="tagRight">body-></div>
  <div id="tagBottom">v body v</div>
```

I couldn't find any mention of this, is this a known bug?

Comment: can you put it to jsfiddle?

Comment: @Raźnyy, why? I already have a working example in the post...